# Sending a Discord webhook through a single class file in java

Tags: java

I was wondering if it would be possible to send a discord webhook using java with the least api's and stuff possible. Just basic java. (Also I only need text so it can be as simple as possible)

The reason I'm asking this is because I want it to be compiled into 1 class file, so that I can run said class file and have it working on its own outside of my IDE. This was possible in unity using networking / web requests, so I assumed it would be something similar for java,  however its more popular to import something which appears to be using maven or gradle (I'm really not familiar with either so I don't know.) I wrote a simple script for unity in order to send the most basic text webhook, and thats it.

So if anyone knows how to use webhooks in one class please let me know!

Edit: I had found this code online somewhere but I don't think you can use it without external libraries because I was unable to import multiple things.

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(webhook_url);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
String jsonMessage = "{\"content\": \"" + content + "\"}";
try {
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonMessage);
    request.setEntity(params);
    response = httpClient.execute(request);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: So in other words you're asking how to send an HTTP request in Java? Why does it have to be in Java? You can do it all in one class which you can compile and run on whatever platform you use that has a JRE.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution to send notifications from a gradle task. Here is what I found during my search

see [json structure of the post message](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/discord_webhook.html) and this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/k3kdude/fba6f6b37594eae3d6f9475330733bdb)

So you have to build a valid JSON message and send it as a post message here is my minimal code to make the webhook work

```java
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONFIG
        String tokenWebhook = "YOUR TOKEN DISCORD WEBHOOK";
        String title = "Your Title";
        String message = "Your Message";
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        String jsonBrut = "";
        jsonBrut += "{\"embeds\": [{"
                + "\"title\": \""+ title +"\","
                + "\"description\": \""+ message +"\","
                + "\"color\": 15258703"
                + "}]}";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(tokenWebhook);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java-DiscordWebhook-BY-Gelox_");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStream stream = con.getOutputStream();
            stream.write(jsonBrut.getBytes());
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            con.getInputStream().close();
            con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Edit the `tokenWebhook` String and fill it with your token, and run the test

Comment: Simple, short, and works great.  Thanks so much!